# What regression analysis technique to use?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I have an independent variable X and dependent variable Y so want too check the impact of X on Y both variables are quantitative ( impact of X quantity on Y quantity ). Also X can be splitted to multiple variable X1,X2,X3... ans i want to check also the impact of X1,X2,X3... on Y (more detailed analysis) so what do you think in both cases the best regression analysis techniques to use ? shoud I just use Simple Linear regression for the fisrt case qnd multiple linear regression for the second case or do you have any better suggestions ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate  more about what do you mean by "*X can be splitted to multiple variable X1,X2,X3...*"? In both cases you will be doing a univariate linear model.

Comment: what I mean is not splitting acually i have already X1,X2,X3... ans the SUM of this variables = X

Comment: OK, so does X has a physical meaning or is this just a artificial variable? I ask because if X_1,X_2... X_p are constrained to sum up to some number or something like that, we need to account for that constraint during modelling. If it is just an artificial surrogate variable with no particular meaning we can directly use X_1,X_2... X_p in a LR setting. :)

Comment: yes actually X have a physical meaning but what do you mean by accounting this constraint into modeling i mean how ?

Answer (score 0):

Those certainly seem like reasonable starting points. Of course, you have to check all the assumptions of the model.